# when php have error redirect to 500 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I can handle all php error except parse and fatal error. When page have fatal or parse error code just give a blank page so how can i redirect 500 page when php have parse or fatal error.

I try htaccess bu nothing happend. 
This is my htaccess codes;

```
ErrorDocument 500 500.php
ErrorDocument 501 500.php
ErrorDocument 502 500.php
ErrorDocument 503 500.php
ErrorDocument 504 500.php
ErrorDocument 505 500.php
ErrorDocument 507 500.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right this is how you can change the default error page for 500 with directive:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

Then you should catch the error

```
error_log = /var/log/apache2/log_name.log  
log_errors = On
```

PHP by default will return a 500 error when this occurs. i haven't done it in years but i think you need to set display_errors to off.

Create a new file and run this inside.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
dummyFunction();
```

Also my advice is to use an error handler that will listen for that error and show the 500 error with everything you need.

Comment: I can change error page with htaccess but problem is php error not throwing to 500 pages and i can't redirect the pages manually because pages have parse error.

Comment: When php have parse error `dummyFunction();` or other codes can not working so then i cant redirect with php codes

Comment: If you were using the mod_proxy_fcgi method to php-fpm there is a directive called "ProxyErrorOverride" you can switch on to force errordocument pages from httpd to be shown instead of those from your backend. Which method do you use to parse php?

Comment: ezra is right you can use proxy to override the errors.